# fail2ban with docker(host mode networking) is making iptables entry but not stopping connections

Tags: iptables, docker, fail2ban

**Environment:**

- Fail2Ban version - 0.9.6
- OS - Debian 9.

**The issue:**

Fail2ban is putting entries in iptables as expected for the jail defined in jail.local as:

```
[xyz_failure]
enabled=true
filter=xyz_failure 
logpath=/var/log/xyz_failure.log  
maxretry=10
findtime=1800
bantime=604800
```

**The output of iptables -S**

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD DROP
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT .  
-N DOCKER
-N DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
-N DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-N DOCKER-USER
-N f2b-xyz_failure
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 0:65535 -j f2b-xyz_failure
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-USER
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o docker0 -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN
-A f2b-xyz_failure -m string --string "X-Forwarded-For: 200.194.41.xxx" --algo bm --to 65535 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable .
```

**Steps to reproduce**
server with docker installed. load balancer in front of server. install fail2ban.

**Observed behavior**
The ip not stopped from accessing website in browser.

**Any additional information**
When i open the website as a webview in the ios app the ip is banned correctly. This seems like an issue of established connections not being banned.

**Here are the logs -**

```
2018-12-06 23:45:13,895 fail2ban.actions [9036]: NOTICE [xyz_failure] Ban 200.194.41.xxx
2018-12-07 00:01:44,627 fail2ban.filter [9036]: INFO [xyz_failure] Found 200.194.41.xxx
2018-12-07 00:01:47,654 fail2ban.filter [9036]: INFO [xyz_failure] Found 200.194.41.xxx
2018-12-07 00:01:53,764 fail2ban.filter [9036]: INFO [xyz_failure] Found 200.194.41.xxx
2018-12-07 00:01:55,767 fail2ban.filter [9036]: INFO [xyz_failure] Found 200.194.41.xxx
2018-12-07 00:01:56,901 fail2ban.filter [9036]: INFO [xyz_failure] Found 200.194.41.xxx
```

**Relevant lines from monitored log files in question:**

```
189.188.53.xxx - - [07/Dec/2018:00:07:02 -0600] User Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.110 Safari/537.36 HTTP_REFERRER:
189.188.53.xxx - - [07/Dec/2018:00:07:20 -0600] User Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.110 Safari/537.36 HTTP_REFERRER:
18.208.165.xxx - - [07/Dec/2018:00:08:15 -0600] User Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.98 Safari/537.36 HTTP_REFERRER: email:
187.254.108.xxx - - [07/Dec/2018:00:08:20 -0600] User Agent:Android app ver 3.3.9 Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0; SM-G950U Build/NRD90M; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/71.0.3578.83 Mobile Safari/537.36 HTTP_REFERRER:
201.175.202.xxx - - [07/Dec/2018:00:08:20 -0600] User Agent:Android app ver 3.3.9 Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 8.1.0; Mi A2 Lite Build/OPM1.171019.019; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/68.0.3440.91 Mobile Safari/537.36 HTTP_REFERRER:
```

Comment: This should be blocking traffic to your host just fine. Or do you mean you want to block traffic going to your Docker containers?

Comment: @MichaelHampton for some reason url being abused still opens up on my browser and fail2ban logs are full of Found 200.194.41.xxx when i access. one more thing is that i usually connect to the servers via ssh so i have an established connection with my ip(netstat -ant | grep EST)

Comment: @MichaelHampton we want to block eventual users, since the docker is in host mode the iptables entries are mirrrored on the host as well.(they are created in the container)

Comment: @MichaelHampton also one more important observation is that when i connect from a webview within the ios app the connection is correctly stopped.(basically url doesnt load in this case)